# The boolean is not getting inherited by children constant

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to read the value of removefromcart via showRemoveFromCart but It's not working, It is not rendering the remove from cart button.
But for some reason I can read the value of addtoCart but not removefromcart.
I think this code should work but visual studio code is saying that value of removefromcart is declared but never read.

````
import ImageHelper from "./helper/ImageHelper"
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom"
import { addItemToCart, removeItemFromCart } from "./helper/cartHelper"

const isAuthenticated = true

const Card = ({product, addtoCart = true, removefromcart = true}) => {
    
    const cartTitle = product ? product.name : "A photo from pexels"
    const cartDescription = product ? product.description : "Default description"
    const cartPrice = product ? product.price : "Default"
    const addToCart = () => {
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        addItemToCart(product, () => {})
        console.log("Added to cart")
      }
      else {
        console.log("Login please")
      }
    }
    const getAredirect = (redirect) => {
      if (redirect) {
        return <Redirect to="/cart"/>
      }
    }
    const showAddToCart = addtoCart => {
      return (
        addtoCart && (<button
          onClick={addToCart}
          className="btn btn-block btn-outline-success mt-2 mb-2"
        >
          Add to Cart
        </button>)
      )
    }
    const showRemoveFromCart = removefromcart => {
      return (
        removefromcart && (
          <button
                onClick={() => {
                  removeItemFromCart(product._id)
                  console.log("Product removed")
                }}
                className="btn btn-block btn-outline-danger mt-2 mb-2"
              >
                Remove from cart
              </button>
        )
      )
    }
    return (
      <div className="card text-white bg-dark border border-info ">
        <div className="card-header lead">{cartTitle}</div>
        <div className="card-body">
          <ImageHelper product={product}/>
          <p className="lead bg-success font-weight-normal text-wrap">
            {cartDescription}
          </p>
          <p className="btn btn-success rounded  btn-sm px-4">{cartPrice}</p>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
              {showAddToCart(addtoCart)}
            </div>
            <div className="col-12">
              {showRemoveFromCart()}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

export default Card ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring *removefromcart* as a parameter of the function on this line:

`const showRemoveFromCart = removefromcart => {`

Since you are calling this function without any arguments, the condition in your code is never met. You can just change your function to not use any parameters and it should work.

`const showRemoveFromCart = () => {`

Comment: Please tell me what code to change. The parameter is "removefromcart" but it is not getting inherited. Thanks for your answer and taking your time.

Comment: Remove argument from `showRemoveFromCart` function as I have written above. If it doesn't help, please provide example in sandbox.

Comment: I solved the problem, You were willing to go out of your way to help me, like seriously thank you so much